# store query result, with multiple results as list variable to use later

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to put the results of a select statement into an @variable to use later on in the query. I dont know how many results there are going to be.
I have tried;

```
SET @variable = SELECT column FROM table
```

RESULT

```
@variable=( 123213,321312,321321)
```

I want to then use the results as

```
UPDATE table SET column=1 WHERE column in @variable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a temporary table:

```
SELECT column
INTO #tmp
FROM table;


UPDATE table
    SET column = 1
    WHERE column in (SELECT column FROM #tmp);
```

You can also use a table variable but that requires specifying the types of the columns to define the variable.

Comment: Amazing. thank you so much. really easy to do it now.

Comment: is there a cleanup command for the #tmp table to clear it for repeat queries. I got a message about #tmp exists- oh drop #tmp?

Comment: @platinums . . . Both temporary tables and table variables are removed at the end of a *stored procedure* block.  If you are doing the code repeatedly within a single code block, then you need to drop the table.

Comment: @platinums A temporary table exists only while a session is active. If you close the session then you'll be able to run the same code again. Otherwise, if you don't want to close the session you'll have to explicitly `DROP` the table - `DROP TABLE #tmp`.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want it to be in the form of a variable (available only at execution time), then you can declare a `TABLE` variable.

```
DECLARE @variable TABLE (Column1 INT);
INSERT INTO @variable
SELECT Column FROM Table
```

The better way would be to create a temporary table with `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT Column
INTO #variable
FROM table;
```

The you can use the `@variable` or `#variable` as a regular table in any query.

```
UPDATE table
SET Column = 1
WHERE column IN (SELECT COLUMN FROM @variable)

or

UPDATE table
SET Column = 1
WHERE column IN (SELECT COLUMN FROM #variable)
```

Although I would prefer / recommend the JOIN style:

```
UPDATE t
SET column = 1
FROM table t
    INNER JOIN #variable v on t.column = v.column
```

There are numerous reasons why **I don't recommend using a table variable** but one of the most important is for **performance** reasons.

The Query Optimizer will always generate an estimate of 1 for when reading data from a table variable, which will generate a less than optimal execution plan for the scenario in which `@variable` has a large number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with multiple values then you should be using `TABLE VARIABLE`

Something like.......

```
Declare @t TABLE (Value INT)

INSERT INTO @t (Value)
SELECT column FROM table
```

Now use this Table variable in your update , something like.....

```
UPDATE table 
 SET column=1 
WHERE column in (Select Value from @t)
```

---

But why cant you just simply select from the table directly when updating records, why do you even need to put it into any kind of variable anyway

```
   UPDATE table 
     SET column=1 
    WHERE column in (SELECT column FROM table)
```

OR better way of doing this would be something like.....

```
   UPDATE t1 
     SET t1.column=1 
   FROM table1 t1 
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON t1.Column = t2.column
```